# Comprobar distribución/versión de Linux y realizar una acción dependiendo del resultado en Bash

Tags: bash, script

Me gustaría saber de que forma puedo comprobar si el sistema que se está utilizando es "Ubuntu" y la versión es la "20.04" en un script bash. En caso afirmativo, continuar todo el proceso y en caso contrario, salir del script.

Ejemplo para comprobación de usuario root:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo
    echo "${RED}Este script debe ejecutarse con privilegios de Administrador." 1>&2
    echo
    exit 1
fi
```

Quiero realizar lo mismo, comprobando que es Ubuntu y la versión 20.04. Con el comando `grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release` puedo obtener esa información, pero no se como filtrarlo en un if con bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haré los ejemplos con `Debian 10`.

- Puedes mirar el fichero [/etc/issue](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/issue.5.html) (OJO se puede modificar, es donde se almacena el mensaje de pre-login ):

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

- Puedes usar el comando [lsb_release](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/lsb_release.1.html) para esto.

```
$ lsb_release -rc
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
$ lsb_release -r | awk '{print $2}'
10
```

- El script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Almacenamos la release en una variable
release="$(lsb_release -r | awk '{print $2}')"

# Comparamos
if [ $release = "10" ]; then
        echo "Release: 10"
else
        echo "Idk."
fi
```

Resultado:

```
$ ./example.sh
Release: 10
```

Comment: Respuesta impecable, he logrado lo que quería sin problema alguno. Gracias.

Comment: Para eso estamos. Me alegro haber sido de ayuda.